# How to enable sortable for portlet again in jquery?

Tags: jquery-ui

I have used Jquery Portlet with sorting.I have cancelled sorting for Portlet-content,portlet-header while maximizing the portlet. Again when i minimize, i want to enable sortable option true.

For Disable sorting i used:

```
$( ".column").sortable( "option", "cancel", '.portlet,.portlet-header,.portlet-content');
```

How to enable sortable for this again?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar approach on my site. I just call the sortable initialization again when I click the minimize button.